# jQuery datepicker not showing current date in all views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using the jquery datepicker and have created an editor template for date fields as well. My code for both is shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
});

@model Nullable<DateTime>

 @{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    if (Model != null)
    {
       dt  = (System.DateTime) Model;

    }
    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", dt.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "date" })
}
```

For some reason the current date is only shown on some views. On the others the date is showing as null 01/01/0001. I have checked and double checked my code and cannot find any problems. I have also checked the outputted html through developer tools and it is identical for fields that show the current date and those that don't - apart from the value of course!

Wondering if anyone else has experienced this. It appears to only be happening on views where there is more than one date field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What controllers/actions back these views in question? How are you populating the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Date coming to your view (some of them), is **NOT null**, but just initialize `new DateTime()`.
That meaas, that it has already set value to *01/01/0001*. And therefore it is not evaluated as null in the `if` statement. so it is not changed to the `DateTime.Now`

To fix it, just convert your if code this way

```
@{
    var date = Model as DateTime?; // local reference to a DateTime? 

    if (!date.HasValue                     // check if it is not null 
        || date.Equals(default(DateTime))) // check if it is not default 01/01/0001
    {
        date = DateTime.Now;
    }

    @Html.TextBox("Name", String.Format("{0:d}", date.Value.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "date" })
 }
```

This will render any passed `DateTime` value which is *meaningful*. In other cases the `DateTime.Now` will be used.

Comment: Just noticed that my validation is failing on date fields now. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Could you, please, get more information? Do you think it is related to that issue? or something new happening?

Comment: My Date field in the Model is as follows: [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Date Customer Added")]
public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

I am unable to submit the form as the validation fails. Definitely think this is related as it wasn't happening before.

Comment: Problem solved! Just noticed @Html.TextBox("Name" in your code. Removed Name and everything is working.

Comment: @Radium On my Edit view the date is being set for fields that were intentionally left as null when the record was created. Just wondering if you new how to only have the current date set on the create view?

Comment: @Radium Sorry struggling with this. I keep getting Nullable object must have a value.

Comment: OK, it seems like a different question to me. Create new question with this issue, and you can get more ideas. It is more design/architectural decision would say. Would you agree?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that somewhere higher on the call stack your Nullable<DateTime> is not a Nullable<DateTime> and thus is getting generated the default value which is what you're seeing in your result.